# creating excel UDF in class library with VS Express

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to use Visual Express editions to make a class library for Excel UDF functions and use it as an add-in?

I am looking for information from ground.

So far, I tried using VS express *C#) 2008
- to make a class library with my pre-defined functions, but compilation error

> [ access denied to write to registry]

I am an administrator and do not understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/) with any edition of Visual Studio (in fact any text editor) to create user defined functions for recent versions of Excel.

If you intend to produce native code .xll add-ins, you will need to use the C language library that is not available with the Express edition.